# What files are essential when sending a command line project for review?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, command-line

I am using Intellij for development of command line java app.

Project Structure

```
|-.git
|-.idea
|-src-|
|     |-main.com....
|     |-test.com....
|
|-out
|-.gitignore
|-Solution.iml
```

Using JDK 10 and JUnit-5

I need to send this project for review.

1. Do i need to send `Solution.iml`, `.idea`? If no how it will know what external libraries i am using? `Git` and `out` are not necessary.
2. I can start `main` and `tests` function by clicking 'run'. But how to run and test without Intellij?
3. Is there any other norm which i need to know of?

Comment: `Solution.iml` is used by Intellij and won't help anyone else.  Is this for a school assignment or work assignment?  I would hope, that in general, folks would tell you how they want you to send the solution.

Comment: Ok..not for school or college.. I know they will review my code and check the output. So i need to send the project with instructions on how to run it and test it.

Comment: If you have `git` in use already, you should use a `.gitignore` file to exclude unnecessary resources (like `*.iml`-files, `idea`-folder, generated code,...; https://gitignore.io/ can be a good helper in creating the needed `.gitignore`-file). This in conjuntion with a build tool (like [maven](https://maven.apache.org/) or [gradle](https://git-scm.com/)) should allow a checkout-and-run workflow (provided, both are configured to create wrappers, which are checked in to the repository).

Comment: You shouldn't send IntelliJ files.  There's no guarantee that any user will have the IDE.  You should be using Maven.  Users should be able to run all your tests by using Maven.  You should create an executable JAR so they can run your main.

Comment: @duffymo Why should they be using Maven? Why shouldn't they use Gradle?

Comment: I should have said "a build tool like Maven".  I have a lot of certificate issues in my corporate setting when I try to use Gradle.  No worries with Maven.

Comment: Besides, nothing wrong with Maven.  Still works well.  Maven is a wonderful for dependency management and build lifecycle if you don't need Groovy scripting.